# How to login inside a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have updated a running cluster with a new image which unfortunately it's crashing. I want to log into the pod to look at logs. What is the way to do so?

```sh
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
codingjediweb-7c45484669-czcpk   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          9m34s
codingjediweb-7c45484669-qn4m5   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          9m32s
```

The application does not generate much console logs. The main logs are in a file. How can I access that file?

```sh
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl logs codingjediweb-7c45484669-czcpk
Oops, cannot start the server.
play.api.libs.json.JsResult$Exception: {"obj":[{"msg":["Unable to connect with database"],"args":[]}]}
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl logs codingjediweb-7c45484669-qn4m5
Oops, cannot start the server.
play.api.libs.json.JsResult$Exception: {"obj":[{"msg":["Unable to connect with database"],"args":[]}]}
```

UPDATE
I tried to implement Christoph's suggestion of using two containers in a pod - one for main application and the other for logging. I switched back to the stable version of my application to be sure that the application is up/running and is generating logs. This would help test that the pattern works. It looks that the logging application keeps existing/crashing.

yaml file

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ cat codingjediweb-nodes.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codingjediweb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: codingjediweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: codingjediweb
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-logs
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: codingjediweb
        image: docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:03072020v2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        env:
        - name: db.cassandraUri
          value: cassandra://xx.yy.xxx.238:9042
        - name: db.password
          value: 9__something
        - name: db.keyspaceName
          value: something2
        - name: db.username
          value: superawesomeuser
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      - name: logging
        image: busybox
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-logs
          mountPath: /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/
        command: ["tail -f /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/*.log"]
```

When I apply the configuration then only one container stays up

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
busybox                          1/1     Running            1          10h
codingjediweb-857c6d584b-n4njp   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m46s
codingjediweb-857c6d584b-s2hg2   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m46s
```

further inspection shows that the main application is up

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl exec -it codingjediweb-857c6d584b-s2hg2 -c logging -- bash
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("logging")
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl exec -it codingjediweb-857c6d584b-s2hg2 -c codingjediweb -- bash
```

And the application is generating logs at the right path

```
root@codingjediweb-857c6d584b-s2hg2:/deploy# tail -f /deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/*.log
2020-07-07 06:40:37,385 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/34.91.191.238:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2020-07-07 06:40:37,389 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/34.91.191.238:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2020-07-07 06:41:07,208 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/34.91.191.238:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2020-07-07 06:41:07,210 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/34.91.191.238:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2020-07-07 06:41:07,271 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/10.44.1.4:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2020-07-07 06:41:07,274 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/10.44.1.4:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2020-07-07 06:41:07,332 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/10.44.2.5:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
2020-07-07 06:41:07,337 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/10.44.2.5:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat query succeeded
2020-07-07 06:41:07,392 [DEBUG] from com.datastax.driver.core.Connection in codingJediCluster-nio-worker-0 - Connection[/34.91.191.238:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a second container in your pod for logging. Just mount the log directory in both containers. The second container can be based on busybox image and do a `tail -f xyz.log`.

```
volumes:
  - name: shared-logs
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: main-app
    image: <your-image>
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-logs
      mountPath: <path/to/logs>
  - name: logging
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-logs
      mountPath: <path/to/logs>
    command: ["tail -f <path/to/logs/*.log>"]
```

Now you can view logs with

```
Kubectl logs <podname> -c logging -f
```

**Update**

Since your log file name is dynamic, you can use the busybox container with an infinite sleep comand, something like `while true; do sleep 86400; done`  should to. Now the logging container does nothing, but still mounts your log file. The other container will crash but the logging container should be running. You can than ssh into it:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod name> -c logging -- sh
```

Or another idea:

You can copy the log directory of the pod to your local system and investigate the logs.

```
kubectl cp <some-pod>:/path/to/logs -c logging /path/to/local/dir
```

Comment: Is service.log suppose to be name of my log file or is it standard name? My log file has a dynamic name :(

Comment: I had two other ideas and updated my answer. Hope one does it :)

Comment: Origin idea is good. Just update to `tail -f <path/to/logs/*.log>` for dynamic name

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. It seems that the logging container exits prematurely.

Comment: Could it be a race condition? the logging runs `tail -f` before the application starts generating logs?

Comment: I have opened this new issue to figure out how to add the while loop. Can you pleae take a look at this (sorry, too new to Kubernetes) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782554/how-to-run-a-script-as-command-in-kubernetes-yaml-file

Comment: got it working. `command: ['sh', '-c', "while true; do sleep 86400; done"]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a shell to a running container. Here is a simple way to do that:

```sh
POD_NAME=odingjediweb-7c45484669-czcpk

kubectl exec --stdin --tty $POD_NAME -- /bin/sh
```

Please note that if the pod resides within a given namespace (other than default), you will need to specify that via `--namespace MY_NAMESPACE`.

Once you have a running session, you can `cd` into your log file and view it.

For additional information, visit https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: thanks. Tried this but got error `error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("codingjediweb")`

Comment: In order to get a shell, the container needs to be in a running state. It appears that yours is not in a running state. Try deleting the pod and wait for a new one to come up to retry. Note that there is probably a very short window before it cashes again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the logs is using a volume in your node with [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).

You can create a `hostPath` and then mount as a volume in your pod. When the container runs, it will generate the log in this directory that is persisted in youe node disk.

> **Note:** If you have more than one node, the directory must exists in all of them.

**Example:**

To use the dir `/mnt/data` of yout node, create the dir with `mkdir -p /mnt/data` and apply the yaml below to create the persistent volume and persistent volume claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Add the `persistentVolumeClaim` and `volumeMounts` in your deployment file, example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: codingjediweb
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: codingjediweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: codingjediweb
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: codingjediweb
        image: docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:03072020v2
        env:
        - name: db.cassandraUri
          value: cassandra://xx.yy.xxx.238:9042
        - name: db.password
          value: 9__something
        - name: db.keyspaceName
          value: something2
        - name: db.username
          value: superawesomeuser
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/deploy/codingjediweb-1.0/logs/"
            name: task-pv-storage
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tested this yet. From what I have read, all replicas need to be on same node for nodePath to work.My application has two replicas. I don't think they run on same node (host) - "Since the hostpath is only available for single host, all replicas should be deployed in a same node (otherwise you may have to use nfs)."

Answer (score -1):

If you want to view the logs just run the following.

`kubectl logs <POD-NAME>`

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned "The application does not generate much console logs. The main logs are in a file. How can I access that file?"

Comment: Ohh yeah, you're right. I missed that part. Sorry about that. Definitely logging into the pods using your answer is the right way.